How is the death of a person marked in Japanese?
I’m compiling a timeline of the Judges of the International Criminal Court. The only judge who died in office so far was Japanese. I want to mark this, ideally with a single graphical symbol (there’s no space for an explanation). In the West, a dagger symbol is often used: †. While this symbol isn’t derived from a Christian cross, it does look a lot like one, so I’m considering using a Japanese symbol in case there is one that’s widely used and understood.
I did some searching to see whether the kanji 死 is used for this purpose, but I couldn’t find any examples of that. I also asked an AI and it suggested to use a chōonpu, but I couldn’t find any examples to corroborate that, either, and in any case that wouldn’t work well in a timeline full of horizontal lines.

So you are trying to find a Japanese symbol to mark the death of the Japanese judge in an English article?

I feel it wouldn’t be appropriate to use something like this in an English-language document.

Besides what is appropriate, you should probably also consider comprehensibility for your readers. Would you also put the judge's dates in office in the Japanese Imperial calendar, to avoid using the AD or CE Gregorian calendar, which very much was derived from a Christian reference? Consider that if you find some possibly obscure Japanese symbol or character that has been used in such a context in the past, nearly all of your non-Japanese-speaking readers and quite possibly some of those who speak Japanese will have no idea what it means, defeating the purpose.

Unless, of course, you define it for them somewhere, in which case you might just use an asterisk, a number, or whatever symbol you please. But I think the very fact that you need to ask here more or less serves as the proof that there is not a symbol that is "widely used and understood" (I daresay even the dagger might mystify many people without context, incidentally).

I assumed the question had to be about a Japanese list, since the OP has asked other Japanese language questions before, but it does certainly sound like the question is about using a Japanese symbol in an English document from this question alone. And I agree that there seems to be no particular reason to do that if that was indeed the intent.

If you need some symbol, the × (ばつ) is often used for this purpose in certain fields, including genetics. See:

ジェノグラム（家族図）の書き方
What do the shapes △ ◯ ╳ ◻ mean in Japanese? And are there variations in meaning, depending on whether or not the shape is filled?

Not many Japanese people are consciously aware of this convention, but the × would be considerably more intuitive and easier to understand than the dagger sign. However, even if you use ×, not everyone will readily understand its meaning, so it would be best to use either × or †, and clearly specify its meaning in a legend.

We use [故]{こ} for the person's name and [没]{ぼつ} for the year/date.
Example:

故安倍晋三
故・安倍晋三
故 安倍晋三
2022年没
2022年7月8日没

As a side note: We use [享年]{きょうねん} for the age of death:

享年67歳

